# Micropython, Store binary file without a filesystem

Tags: micropython, nios

I'm using Micropython on a Nios 2 Softcore from Altera. I somehow need to load a image file into a Flash. I've tried to wrap this file into a Python string which I then could load from the processor it self. However due to how a string is processed in MicroPython this was not possible. There is generated a hash value for every string and the speed and size of this hash string is proportional with the size of the string length it self.

I do not have a files system on this Nios, all python modules are compile from the Memzip folder (no frozen modules though).

Is there a way to compile a binary file which can be imported or access in other ways through the REPL?

I have tried to make a wrapper for the file and add the data as binary but my 33MB file gets expanded to 200MB and I run out of ram

Regards

Comment: I would ask this on the [MicroPython forum](http://forum.micropython.org/).

Comment: Yes i did that. Think I will post the solution here once I get it down

Comment: Did you get an answer? Can you share it? (Let's not send people away to the MicroPython forum. StackOverflow is much better for these kinds of Q&A.)

Comment: Sorry no. No solution yet